# Higher order function in java, how to write a method that take no parameter and return a Map which Map's value is a method i java

Tags: java

I want a method that takes no parameter, then return a map(a,b) that b is a method that is a list of string

Comment: `Map<Object, Supplier<List<String>>>`

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: Hi frianH, I wrote this, don't know if it correct.

myMethod(Map<String, () -> {
        new LinkedList<String>()
    }>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding from @donquih0te's answer, you can use a map of whatever your key is to a Supplier:

```
Map<Object, Supplier<List<String>>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("foo", () -> List.of("bar"));
Supplier<List<String>> = map.get("foo");
List<String> result = supplier.get();
System.out.println(result);
```